# Как лучше отделить логику от инфтерфейса ввода-вывода

Tags: ооп

Насколько я знаю при написание приложения лучше отделять логику от инфтерфейса ввода-вывода. Т.е. делать одни классы для логики, а другие для инфтерфейса ввода-вывода.  Как лучше установить взаимоотношения между этими классами?
Т.е. например я пишу приложение которое читает инфу из файла, преобразует её некоторым образом, а потом записывает в другой файл. Т.е. у меня есть у меня будет два класса одина описывающий логику, а другой описываючий получение и запись в файл. Какие отношения между ними лучше установить.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов — определить для классов операторы ввода-вывода в потоки.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const my_class&);
friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream&, my_class&);
```

Comment: У меня по услвию к сожалению нельзя перегружать опраторы... И создавать друзей у меня по условию также не рекомендуется. И я вот решил сделать класс MANADGER который будет как бы обёрткой над классом CALC (CALC - класс с логикой), и в котором будут реализованы методы ввода-вывода. Т.е. в  классе MANADGER обьявлено поле с обьектом класса CALC, а также необходимые методы для ввода-вывода. Соответственно меня мучает вопрос, это правильное решение, или есть более предпочтительные методы, как это можно организовать?